# Chrome HID API extensions support

Tags: api, google-chrome, hid

Does Chrome HID API are supported by extensions or only by apps? Chrome apps will be phased out and we need to understand if HID API can be used with extensions

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it is disabled in chrome extesnions.

The only exceptions are Google's own U2F extensions, that are built-in and use HID. However those cannot be modified by user.